# Getting electric indent behaviour for added chars to "electric-indent-chars"

Tags: indentation, electric-indent

I am trying to get electric indent behaviour in bazel BUILD files.  These are essentially python files, although the structure is extremely simple.

Let me give you an example:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    deps = [
        ":hello-greet",
        "//lib:hello-time",
    ],
)
```

What I want is to have electric indentation behaviour for "]" and ")".

What I have tried is:

- to add these characters to `electric-indent-chars`
- to add `electric-indent-post-self-insert-function` to `post-self-insert-hook`

Neither of these steps seems to change the behaviour of the characters.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What major mode are you using?  Does TAB-indentation work in it?

Comment: Major mode is derived from python-mode.  TAB runs 'indent-for-tab-command' and indents the way I want.

Comment: Update: python.el sets 'electric-indent-inhibit' to avoid automatic indentation so 'electric-indent-chars' is never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your major mode derives from `python-mode`, than you likely need to make it

```
(setq-local electric-indent-inhibit nil)
```

As for why it's non-nil: `python-mode` sets this vars to a non-nil value because electric-indent is usually undesirable when indentation is syntactically significant (as in Python).

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is slightly more complicated than Stefan's answer, so it might be worth recording the details.

```
(defun rr-enable-electric-indent ()
  (setq-local electric-indent-inhibit nil)
  (add-to-list 'electric-indent-chars ?\))
  (add-to-list 'electric-indent-chars ?\]))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'rr-enable-electric-indent)
```